# Coldfusion 9 serializeJSON()

Tags: json, coldfusion, adobe, coldfusion-9, cfml

Anytime that I use serializeJSON in cf9 the JSON it returns is prepended with '//'. This is pretty frustrating because even coldfusion will throw an error trying to decode that as json. For example:

```
var a = { stuff = 'some content' };
a = serializejSON( a ); // the content of a is now: //{"STUFF":"some content"}
b = deserializeJSON( a );
```

The above code will throw an error saying something like 'unable to parse character at position 1: /'. In order to make this work I have to do a string replace and swap out '' for the '//'.

I can't seem to find any information on this issue. Is this some sort of feature that I don't understand and is working as intended? Am I missing some sort of setting that fixes this?

Comment: you can change the setting the CF Admin under Server Settings > Settings. Disable the "Prefix serialized JSON with" field

Comment: @MattBusche you should promote your comment to an answer. That is definitely where the `//` is coming from. But keep in mind that recommending to disable that setting is introducing a potential security risk.  Just to make the OP and others aware.

Comment: @MattBusche - Could you please update your answer to mention the [security implications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501123/coldfusion-10-returnformat-json-adding-characters) of disabling that feature? In case the next guy reading it does not know about it and applies it without understanding the ramifications..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can disable this in the ColdFusion administrator. Go to Server Settings > Settings and uncheck `Prefix serialized JSON with`

There are, however, security implications if you turn this off. This helps protect your JSON data from cross-site scripting attacks and is explained more in depth in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15501182/1065868)

Answer (score 0):

*Quick update*: A guy previously submitted a bug ticket to Adobe to disable the secure JSON prefix of the `SerializeJSON` function in the form of an attribute..

[Ticket [Fixed]](https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-3040329)

Since then Adobe obliged and added the attribute `useSecureJSONPrefix` onto the `SerializeJSON` funtion.

[Documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/serializejson.html)

That way you can keep the secure setting in ColdFusion Administrator and simply disabled it where you don't need it.