# Jquery Autocomplete Not showing Dropdown

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, coldfusion

I know that this question has been asked many times before, but seems like there are many, many different reasons that it doesn't work and every one is a little different.

I believe my problem is in my JSON response. (I am using ColdFusion if that is a factor). I made a blank test page to try this on, so I know nothing else could be messing it up.

I created a test autocomplete with just an array of values (WORKS).

```
$("##txtLanguage").autocomplete({ source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"] });
```

However, I am trying to get a dynamic autocomplete to work. I am using it with a cfc and am receiving a response. However, the autocomplete for that field does not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("##txtLanguage").autocomplete({ source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"] });

        $("##name").autocomplete({
            source: function(query, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/cfc/autocomplete.cfc?method=queryNames&returnformat=json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        searchPhrase: query.term
                    },
                    success: function(result) {
                        response(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is a sample response that I am receiving. I believe the issue is with the "//" double slashes that are at the beginning of that response.

[image: Sample response received]

---

**Full page code:**

```
<cfset pageTitle = "Self Help Admin">

<cfoutput>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("##txtLanguage").autocomplete({ source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"] });

        $("##name").autocomplete({
            source: function(query, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/cfc/autocomplete.cfc?method=queryNames&returnformat=json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        searchPhrase: query.term
                    },
                    success: function(result) {
                        response(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<form>
    test    <input type="text" id="txtLanguage"/>
    User: <input type="text" id="name" />
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<br>
</cfoutput>
```

**Full cfc Code:**

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cfinclude template = "init.cfm">

    <!--- ================================================================== --->
    <!---                  user Autocomplete                                 --->
    <!--- ================================================================== --->   
    <cffunction name="queryNames" access="remote">
        <cfargument name="searchPhrase">

        <cfquery name="query_names" dataSource="#dsn.yTen#">
            SELECT    name
            FROM      users
            WHERE     LOWER(name) LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' value="%#LCASE(arguments.searchPhrase)#%">
            ORDER BY  name
        </cfquery>

        <cfset result = arrayNew(1) >

        <cfloop query="query_names">
            <cfset ArrayAppend(result, query_names.Name)>
        </cfloop>

        <cfreturn result>
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: *I believe the issue is with the "//" double slashes* Good guess.  It is protection against cross-site scripting attacks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501123/coldfusion-10-returnformat-json-adding-characters

Comment: thanks for that. It says that you can override that setting in the cffunction. would you happen to know how?

Comment: I do not believe it can be overridden in the cffunction. However, it can be disabled on a per app basis in the Application.cfc (use with caution) OR you can also handle it by adding the `$.ajaxSetup({`  function shown here: http://web.archive.org/web/20130117041105/http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/11/8/Handling-JSON-with-prefixes-in-jQuery-and-jQueryUI

Comment: figured it out please submit an answer and i will accept it. the option to disable it per function is to add:  secureJSON="false" to the cffunction

Comment: Honestly I forgot about that one, so *you* should post it as an answer :) Nice job!

Comment: Nothing to do with the original issue, but a) do not forget to var/local scope the function local variables, ie query_names and result and b) it is a good practice to include a type/returntype for arguments and cffunctions

Comment: Yeah I would of put the returnType in but it was in my url in the Ajax call so i omitted it in the function. will add scope to the variables thanks

Comment: You may be thinking of `returnformat`, which is different. Keeping the format in the URL is good, as it makes the function is more flexible. However, the `returntype` stays the same, regardless of format, so it can be set to array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Leigh pointed out this is to prevent Cross-Site Scripting Attacks. and pointed me to the following solution:

[Coldfusion 10 returnformat="JSON" adding characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501123/coldfusion-10-returnformat-json-adding-characters)

After reading that solution I found that you can disable it per [cffunction](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-f/cffunction.html) by adding this as an attribute:

`secureJSON="false"`

after including that everything worked as expected.