# Ajax call SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, coldfusion

I am trying to make an ajax call using jquery and setting session variables using Coldfusion 10. This is the error I am receiving:

 `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

[image]

Am I overlooking something?

```
$('#ToolTables_processing_1').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        // the location of the CFC to run
        url: "redirects/selectedrows.cfm",
        // send a GET HTTP operation
        type: "post",
        // tell jQuery we're getting JSON back
        dataType: "json",
        // send the data to the CFC
         data: $('#form').serialize(),
        // this gets the data returned on success
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            window.location = 'forms/exitinterviewpdf.cfm';
        }, 
        // this runs if an error
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // show error
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

If I take out the `datatype: json` I just get an empty string.
[image]

selectedrows.cfm

```
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowName = form.selectedRowName >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowtodayDate = form.selectedRowtodayDate >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowtitle = form.selectedRowtitle >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowdepartment = form.selectedRowdepartment >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowhireDate = form.selectedRowhireDate >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowterminationDate = form.selectedRowterminationDate >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowreasonLeaving = form.selectedRowreasonLeaving >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowfeelPay = form.selectedRowfeelPay >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowprogressHere = form.selectedRowprogressHere >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowanotherJob = form.selectedRowanotherJob >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowcomparewith = form.selectedRowcomparewith >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowhigherSalary = form.selectedRowhigherSalary >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowpreventLeaving = form.selectedRowpreventLeaving >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowclearlyExplained = form.selectedRowclearlyExplained >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowbyWhom = form.selectedRowbyWhom >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowadequateTraining = form.selectedRowadequateTraining >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowworkPerform = form.selectedRowworkPerform >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowworkingCondition = form.selectedRowworkingCondition >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowsalary = form.selectedRowsalary >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowretirement = form.selectedRowretirement >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowhealthPlan = form.selectedRowhealthPlan >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowtuition = form.selectedRowtuition >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowunileave = form.selectedRowunileave >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowcoworkers = form.selectedRowcoworkers >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowsupervisionReceived = form.selectedRowsupervisionReceived >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowneededHelp = form.selectedRowneededHelp >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowmanagerRespond = form.selectedRowmanagerRespond >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowsuggestionsBetterPlace = form.selectedRowsuggestionsBetterPlace >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowrealReasonForLeaving = form.selectedRowrealReasonForLeaving >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowcomments = form.selectedRowcomments >

<cfoutput>#SerializeJSON(session.exitinterview.selected)#</cfoutput>
```

Errors where its breaking
[image]

[image]

For VLAD
[image]

Comment: What happens if you hard-code some JSON as response in redirects/selectedrows.cfm ? It seems redirects/selectedrows.cfm does not return anything. Can you post the code in selectedrows.cfm?

Comment: Why are you using a .cfm page instead of a .cfc? Though technically you can post to a .cfm script, it makes it a LOT harder to control the output and easier to inadvertently break an ajax call then using a .cfc.

Comment: Try 1 form field first. Ex try to post and send selectedRowName=David first. This way you can narrow down the problem if its in your form values or the problem might be the selectedrows.cfm page

Comment: @AlexBaban above i posted the only code in selectedrows.cfm

Comment: @Leigh so i can just change it to a cfc and call it the same way?

Comment: @Vlad I tried that its throwing the errors and breakpoints i showed above

Comment: @Leigh If I change it to cfc it says the same thing

Comment: (Edit) 1) What is the actual *response* string returned from the .cfm/.cfc? 2) Please post your .cfc code. Scale back the example to use a single form field, as Vlad suggested. Using only the minimum amount of code makes it easier for you, and others, to identify the problem. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am guessing the response either contains extra debugging info or possibly extra characters like `//`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501123/coldfusion-10-returnformat-json-adding-characters

Comment: Please post your cfc code and I will try it out.

Comment: @DavidBrierton I tried it out and it looks to be working. Please try adding <cfcontent reset="true" > above
<cfoutput>#SerializeJSON(session.exitinterview.selected)#</cfoutput>

Comment: Please try out this code. Html page http://trycf.com/gist/249df7bb2014d1581d8da32acb8fc7ac/acf2016?theme=monokai and the Selectedrows.cfm http://trycf.com/gist/c1ecc657f9ffdd331d896dfdb4bf4904/acf2016?theme=monokai

Comment: i have an application.cfc in that folder that apparently was throwing everything off because i commented almost everything out of it and its now working

Comment: thanks for the help i guess application.cfc throw that ajax stuff off

Comment: As it runs before every request, an Application.cfc can definitely interfere with an ajax request, depending on what the code inside it is doing. What line(s) were causing the problem?  Writing it up as an answer would help the next guy.

Comment: i duno even know i just commented the entire thing out except the name and session stuff and then it worked ughhh what a pain. Two days all because of an application cfc smh

Comment: Heh, we have all been there. It is the kind of thing you only have to learn once. *i duno even know* Throw it up on github or pastebin and I am sure someone can point out the problem, so someone can at least benefit from your pain ;-)

Comment: @Vlad do you want to post the answer to get credit? The reason i solved this was because i realized it from your example

Comment: I will post an answer. Thanks for acknowledging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do when debugging large data sets is narrow down the problem. Please try the sample codes

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form id="form" method="post" onsubmit="javascript:return(false)">

    <input type="text" name="SELECTEDROWNAME" id="SELECTEDROWNAME" value="Vlad" >   
    <input type="submit" id="ToolTables_processing_1" value="save" >    

</form>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

    $('#ToolTables_processing_1').on('click', function () {

        $.ajax({
            // the location of the CFC to run
            url: "redirects/selectedrows.cfm",
            // send a GET HTTP operation
            type: "post",
            // tell jQuery we're getting JSON back
            dataType: "json",
            // send the data to the CFC
             data: $('#form').serialize(),
            // this gets the data returned on success
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                //window.location = 'forms/exitinterviewpdf.cfm';
            }, 
            // this runs if an error
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // show error
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});//doc ready

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

selectedrows.cfm

```
    <cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowName = form.selectedRowName >
<!---<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowtodayDate = form.selectedRowtodayDate >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowtitle = form.selectedRowtitle >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowdepartment = form.selectedRowdepartment >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowhireDate = form.selectedRowhireDate >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowterminationDate = form.selectedRowterminationDate >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowreasonLeaving = form.selectedRowreasonLeaving >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowfeelPay = form.selectedRowfeelPay >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowprogressHere = form.selectedRowprogressHere >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowanotherJob = form.selectedRowanotherJob >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowcomparewith = form.selectedRowcomparewith >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowhigherSalary = form.selectedRowhigherSalary >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowpreventLeaving = form.selectedRowpreventLeaving >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowclearlyExplained = form.selectedRowclearlyExplained >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowbyWhom = form.selectedRowbyWhom >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowadequateTraining = form.selectedRowadequateTraining >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowworkPerform = form.selectedRowworkPerform >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowworkingCondition = form.selectedRowworkingCondition >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowsalary = form.selectedRowsalary >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowretirement = form.selectedRowretirement >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowhealthPlan = form.selectedRowhealthPlan >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowtuition = form.selectedRowtuition >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowunileave = form.selectedRowunileave >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowcoworkers = form.selectedRowcoworkers >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowsupervisionReceived = form.selectedRowsupervisionReceived >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowneededHelp = form.selectedRowneededHelp >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowmanagerRespond = form.selectedRowmanagerRespond >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowsuggestionsBetterPlace = form.selectedRowsuggestionsBetterPlace >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowrealReasonForLeaving = form.selectedRowrealReasonForLeaving >
<cfset session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowcomments = form.selectedRowcomments >--->
<cfsetting showdebugoutput="false">
<cfcontent reset="true" >
<cfoutput>#SerializeJSON(session.exitinterview.selected)#</cfoutput>
```

As others suggested it can be some malformed JSON data and as you figured it out some code in the Application.cfc is the problem.