# ColdFusion serializeJSON adding // characters

Tags: json, coldfusion, youtube-api

I have written some code to interact with the YouTube API, on development it works fine - on acceptance it doesn't!

I have found that the output from serializeJSON is adding //

```
        <cfset jsonUpdateVideo={
        "id"= "#arguments.videoId#",            
         "snippet"= {
         "title"= "#arguments.title#",
         "description"= "#arguments.description#",
         "tags"= [#trim(lstTags)#],
         "categoryId"= "28"
        },
          "status"= {
          "privacyStatus"= "#arguments.privacy#",
          "embeddable"= True,
          "license"= "youtube"
          }
    }>
```

The result of

> serializeJSON(jsonUpdateVideo)

is

```
//{"status":{"embeddable":true,"privacyStatus":"Private","license":"youtube"},"snippet":{"description":"More information about this video can be found at some URL","categoryId":28,"title":"Video Test","tags":["\"tag1\", \"tag2\", \"tag3\", \"tag4\", \"tag4\", \"tag5\""]},"id":"_jI4GfjnGCM"}
```

If I paste this into the YouTube API Explorer without the // it works fine and updates the video details.

Not sure where the // comes from since it's ok on Development.

Comment: By calling it a 'comment' instead of '//' I found a possible solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146365/coldfusion-8-serializejson-outputting-with-a-comment

Answer (score 2):

In the ColdFusion administration there is an option.

Prefix serialized JSON with 
//

Protects web services which return JSON data from cross-site scripting attacks by prefixing serialized JSON strings with a custom prefix.

This was enabled in one environment and not the other, now I can enable it in both - and I guess I strip it out manually.

Now I know what to search for, I am finding more answers...
[Coldfusion 10 returnformat="JSON" adding characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501123/coldfusion-10-returnformat-json-adding-characters)